# Proving $\Phi$ is differentiable and find $D \Phi$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $E = \{ f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} : f(0)=0 , f $ is continuously differential$ \}$

With $||f|| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f'(t)|$ and Let $\Phi(f)(t) = \int \limits_{0}^{t} f(u)du$ with $||f|| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|$,

prove that $\Phi$ is differentiable and compute $D\Phi$ ?

I need hint make sense of the question, like the limits is over real numbers or function that there norm tends to zero.

Comment: $\Phi(f+h)(t)=\ldots$

Comment: $\Phi(f+h)(t)$ = $\Phi(f)(t) + \Phi(h)(t)$ , but how does this helps ? @Fakemistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $\Phi(af+bg)=a\Phi(f)+b\Phi(g)$. This implies that $\Phi$ il linear and equal to its derivative.